# how can I create theme that customize user in asp.net web Application?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, themes

I am Developing a web Application in ASP.NET 3.5. I have to create UI that customize user. That means, user change their profile Background Color, Fore color, size, etc. 
How Can I create this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a profile, then create a page to read/write these values to/from the profile:

http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you must use them in asp.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247256%28v=vs.100%29.aspx